# In-app purshase Restore process

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

There might be a ton of questions related to the same topic but i just dont understand what Restore purchases mean and what restore button apple wants me to implement in my app.

Please can someone reply to this question, i am new to this and this is my first application.
i am kinda lost a little. Thanks

Restore button means that :
 when the user pushes it, it restores the already purchased item as in, it return what ever he purchased and get money back
 **OR**
does it simply mean that the user can re-download whatever he already purchased without paying for it twice?(if he deleted and re-installed the app)

if it is the second one, don't apple checks for that ? and set an alert for"You've already purchased this. Tap ok to download it again"

I implemented in my code a restore button , is it enough ? is that all apple wanted?

```
////Restore button tapped
{
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}


// Then this is called form the code Above
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {
NSLog(@"Restore Tapped in transaction process");
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

//Then This
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {
NSLog(@"%@",queue );
NSLog(@"Restored Transactions are once again in Queue for purchasing %@",[queue transactions]);

NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);

for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {
    NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
    [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
    NSLog (@"product id is %@" , productID);

    ***////HERE////
what should i do here? 
delete the item, as it is restored OR re-download it ?(depends on the question i asked above)***


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restoring purchases is to re-enable or re-download a previous purchase without having to pay for it again. Yes, the store does check if the user selects to buy and shows an alert, but the restore process is cleaner (from a user point of view) than setting up a new purchase (which seems wrong from a user point of view when you already purchased it before).

Restoring purchases creates new transactions for each previously completed valid transaction so your handling should be done outside of `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` (it would be handled by the same code which handled the original transaction `updatedTransactions`).